# Streaming and shell. Trivial query

Tags: python

The contents of the file *a.py* are:

```
a = input()  
print(a)
```

and *fearless.txt* contains the string : *pink floyd.*

Now, when I simply type in `%a.py < fearless.txt` at the command prompt (windows), it gives an error "lost.stdin".

However, when I type `%python a.py < fearless.txt`, no error occurs.

I don't understand this, given that .py is a recognized extension and is run by python. Shouldn't then, both be equivalent?
Note I'm using the symbol `%` in place of the actual directory.
( Python version : 3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601 and winXP-32 bit. )

Comment: What version of Python do you have? (Not just "2.7" or "3.4", but full 3-number version?) And are `.py` files actually run by Python on your system, as in `C:\Python34\Python.exe`, or by the `py` launcher (as described in [`PEP 397`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/))?

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: I'll note that this appears to be a Windows-specific problem. While I'm not sure the purpose of the code (print the first line of the file?), it works fine in OS X both ways.

Comment: @abarnet, via command line prompt of the windows OS. Not the shell. Not the launcher.

Comment: @cge: As you guessed, that's all there is to it. Take a text from a file, stream to the input of the module, which in turn streams it to the command-line shell.

Comment: @Abhishek, how was the greying background achieved?

Comment: While I don't know *why* this is happening, losing stdin is a Python error. My expectation is that the wrong interpreter is running it, for some reason, or, for some reason, when Windows has to find the correct interpreter, Windows does not attach it to stdin and stdout correctly.

Comment: @Fullmetal http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting :)

Comment: @abarnet I understand your question now. in the first case, it's via the py launcher, which detects a.py, but in the second case, via python.exe to which I've set a path. Read the comments under poke's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on how the `.py` files are registered. It should work when the `py.exe` launcher is set up correctly. You can verify this by looking up the following key in the registry: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command`. The default value should be `"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%1" %*`.

You can also try using the following instead:

```
type fearless.txt | a.py
```

---

I just noticed that you are using Windows XP. The problem you are seeing might be because of an old Windows bug with redirection. It was said to be fixed at some point, but maybe XP was still partially affected. I suggest you to update your system anyway because Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: okay does *%a.py < fearless.txt* and *%python a.py < fearless.txt* both work just fine on your OS (which is?)

Comment: Okay, this is odd. Now I've run python in the second case by setting *path = D:\Python34\ . Are you saying in the first case, a.py is run by this py.exe thingy in C:\WINDOWS\py.exe (No clue what the %1 and %* thing means there. ) which happens to be the value in that key you mentioned, but in the second case runs python from D:\Python34\ ? If you can clarify this and point a few other nuances? If so, comment back and if I'm satisfied, incorporate the nuances and et. al. into your answer.  I believe my hunch is right. Awaiting reply. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, both work for me (on Windows 8). If the registry is set up to use the Python launcher (which is the case with all current Python versions), then running a `.py` file on its own will use the Python launcher `py.exe`. If you have the Python location in your PATH though, you can *also* use `python a.py` to call it with the executable directly. So the former will use `py.exe` and delegate it to `D:\Python34\Python.exe` while the latter will directly call `D:\Python34\Python.exe`.

Comment: And the inevitable question (:P) : If py.exe delegates it to pythone.exe and eventually both run the same executable to run their scripts, why the difference and the throwing of an exception in the former case?

Comment: I have no idea… :D (Sorry about that ^^)

Answer (score -1):

If this is on a Unix system (as I'm guessing it is), you'll need to have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the top of the file to tell the kernel that this is a file whose contents need to be executed by the specified interpreter. The `.py` extension is just a detail and is not used to decide "how to run" the given program.

When you try to run the file without the shebang, it's being executed by your current shell and that's what's giving you the errors. Python doesn't even come into the picture.

Comment: It's windows, as stated above. And since typing *filename.py* at the command prompt (of windows) runs it, windows does know 'how to run' it. With that premise, if you reread my question, that'll clear up for you, I hope.

Comment: fudge. a downvote for just getting the os wrong? ain't that harsh?